# Python unpacking operator / unpack subquery in separated columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Python there is the unpacking operator (*), which allows you to take an iterator or iterable (tuple, list, generator, etc.) and pass each of its items as an argument to a function. I want to do the same thing with a Postgresql subquery. But I can't find any information anywhere.

I want to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tabla1(a, b, c) SELECT a, *(SELECT b, c FROM tabla2 LIMIT 1) FROM tabla3
```

To avoid doing two almost identical selects and speed up my queries.
I want to AVOID something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tabla1(a, b, c) SELECT a, (SELECT b FROM tabla2 LIMIT 1), (SELECT c FROM tabla2 LIMIT 1) FROM tabla3
```

I tried the following:

- review documentation
- use with statement (It doesn't work for me because I can't relate a query column to the subquery, which would be necessary for me)
- Read a question from this site (I don't have the link)

My question would be, is there something similar to that in Postgresql or any way to affect multiple columns with a single subquery? For example, something like the with statement with which you can do `name_of_the_query.column`?

#### Edit

This is the query I did with with, the test query with real names, I hope it makes my question better quality.

```
WITH ztabla02 AS (SELECT (CASE WHEN LEFT(maecuent.cuenta, 1) IN ('1','2','3') THEN
                  array[(SELECT descripcio FROM ztabla02 WHERE c_tabla='PR' AND c_clave=maecuent.cod_pcia), 'ARGENTINA']
                 ELSE
                 array['', (SELECT descripcio FROM ztabla02 WHERE c_tabla='PA' AND c_clave=maecuent.cod_pcia)]
                 END) 
                 AS tuple)
                 
SELECT ztabla02.tuple[1], ztabla02.tuple[2] FROM maecuent
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  falta una entrada para la tabla «maecuent» en la cláusula FROM
LINE 1: WITH ztabla02 AS (SELECT (CASE WHEN LEFT(maecuent.cuenta, 1)...
                                                 ^
```

Comment: Not sure where `a` comes from.  `INSERT INTO tabla1(a, b, c) SELECT a, b, c FROM tabla2 LIMIT 1` ?

Comment: @Serg I put "a" separately to show that it belongs to other table. I see that the published queries are incomplete. Sorry, edited. But thanks anyway for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a CTE

```
  with t2 as (
      SELECT b, c FROM tabla2 LIMIT 1
  )
  INSERT INTO tabla1(a, b, c) 
  SELECT t3.a, t2.b, t2.c
  FROM tabla3 t3
  CROSS JOIN t2
```

Note LIMIT without ORDER BY will return an arbitrary row.

Comment: I've already tried with, but I can't relate the column of one table to the other. I'm going to edit the question with the actual query I got from retrying using with. Thanks anyway for your answer!